# How can I dynamically determine which model a controller is controlling?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, model, controller, activesupport

I'm writing a Rails plugin, and need to be able to dynamically determine which model a controller is associated with. For example, if I have a PeopleController, I need a clean way to determine that the controller handles Person models.

I've had a look through the API and haven't found a method for it.

Is the only way to do this as a regexp combined with some `ActiveSupport` inflection trickery like `singularize`?

If so, are there any pitfalls with this approach? What are the edge cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only a convention that a controller and model are related, so there is really no way to do it.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm dynamically adding ajax validation methods in the controller. Something like this: `ajax_validates_for :first_name, :last_name`. 
I guess I'll just require a first parameter that is the model name that the attributes exist for: `ajax_validates_for :person, :first_name, :last_name`. Thanks!

Comment: yeah, that's probably the easiest appraoch

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are following the Rails naming convention for model and controller names, you can do the following to get the model name/class.

```
# In a controller instance
klass = controller_name.classify.constantize
```

Answer (score 0):

Iam just modifing a litle KandadaBoggu answer to make it more automatic for any instance of the controller.

```
# In a controller instance
klass_name = self.class.to_s.gsub(/Controller$/, '').singularize
klass = klass_name.constantize
```